# how to run Farma in R for Windows

Tags: r

I have downloaded and installed the Farma Package for R successfully in Windows(So does the command window says).But when I tried to display the object "arimaSim" the software says "object not found". I am trying to learn Farma (for Prediction) by my own and now I am helpless that I cannot go further since I am not sure what is wrong with my software. Please suggest some alternative ways If any.

Comment: Did you load the package with `library(fArma)` ? By the way, it seems to be `armaSim` and not `arimaSim`.

Comment: Hi @juba, First i have tried using the option "packages" given in the toolbox. That did not work properly. Hence I searched an alternative way like I downloaded the zip file and installed. Every time the installation was running successfully. But the thing is that while trying to work on it(tried some simple programs available in Internet), the software returns error.

Comment: Ok, but even if a package is installed, you have to load it with `library` before being able to use it. Did you do it ?

Comment: Oops..!! @juba Actually I was unaware of that.I am entirely new to this software package. I was using the pdf tutorial to support my work. I guess I did not get it fully. Could you please suggest the further proceeding that I have to do to make my tool work..

Comment: Well, without a doubt, the further proceeding would be to read an introduction to R. It will be very difficult to use the extension without a minimal understanding of R base.

Comment: @juba.Thanking You for the suggestion..:)